# How to detect whether user is actively in the web app?

Tags: web-applications, cross-platform

I'd like to know whether it's possible (and how) to detect whether a user is actively in a web app (aka in the browser tab) and not on another website. If also like to relay the information to a web based portal and to have this work with all (or at least Chrome) browsers and on iOS and Android.
This would be used in a classroom situation where teachers would be able to control exactly what the students are doing and know if they are not doing what they're supposed to.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  You just want to know if the user has a page of your site/app open?  Or if it's actively on their screen?

Comment: "... and not on another web site" is a problem - not possible to detect server side.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Brandon: I want to be able to detect whether they have it actively on their screen.

Comment: @DanPichelman: I'm trying to create an in class solution for my school in which teachers would be able to see if the students are doing what their supposed to be doing and aren't on another website. In other words, for teachers to be able to control exactly what the kids are doing in the class.

Comment: If it's not possible to do in a Web App, does someone know how to do it with just an iOS or Android app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking whether current web browsers do or do not implement a certain feature. An authoritative answer to that belongs on an up-to-date Javascript reference site.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a technical solution to a non-technical problem.

Technically, with JavaScript, you can [know if the current tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060008/240613). This doesn't mean that the users won't be able to (very easily) circumvent it, for instance by tampering JavaScript.

In a classroom, instead of focusing on control, focus on the result. Are students doing something else because the exercise is too boring? Or maybe because they have too much time? If you're concerned about students accessing websites which are not suited for schools, you should address the concern to the system administrator who needs to block specific websites at the lower level.